# Does manager have right to control your leave usage?

Tags: manager

My company has a rule to bring forward only 5 leaves from this year to the following year.

I was going to take my remaining leaves at the end of December. After some time passed, I decided not to go at the end of December, but in mid December.

But my manager will not allow me to take leave in mid December (I told him before I would be taking leave at the end of December, but hadn't applied on the system yet) and asks me to take leave at the end of December instead.

Does your manager have the right to control when you spend your leave?

Comment: Questions seeking advice on company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies should be directed to your manager or HR department. Questions that address only a specific company or position are of limited use to future visitors. Questions seeking legal advice should be directed to legal professionals - Voting to close as off topic

Comment: Unfortunately this varies from company to company and from country to country.  With where I work management can refuse your request for leave if they would be too short staffed for that period of time and/or other people already request that time off before you did.

Comment: What would they do if you were in the hospital?  (Think about it.)

Answer (score 4):

> Does manager have right to control when you need to spend your leave?

Virtually any company has an HR package the spells out the details for how you can take vacation/leave time.

Check it. My guess is that you'll find language that tells you that your leave must be coordinated with your manager. That's usually done so the company can balance time off and not leave a team short-handed.

If that's the case, then Yes - your manager has the right to control when you can spend your leave.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say where this is, but most likely he can. Especially since he may have prepared for you not being there at the end of the month. He might have made promises that required you to work in mid December.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have the right to take the leave that you have accrued.
2. Your management gets to sign off on any leave you want to take.

I just can't think of any multi-employee business on planet Earth - especially an international business - where any employee can take accrued leave whenever they feel like it. Management has a a business to run and the business must be there to service its customers at all times the business is officially open. If they kill your leave time because they are getting short-handed, they'll probably compensate you in same way by say, paying you at the end of the year for the leave that you didn't get a chance to take.

Your taking leave is not an absolute entitlement. It is an entitlement that is conditional on your management letting you take it. The management's first priority is protecting the health and the smooth functioning of the business they are running. The management's first priority is certainly not to protect your right to your leave whenever you or anyone they manage want to take a leave. Some leaves are sacrosanct or nearly sacrosanct by culture and tradition. Examples: Christmas in the case of a Western business, Diwali in the case of an Indian firm, Yom Kippour in the case of an Israeli business. Beyond that, the leaves are taken by mutual accommodation between staff and management.